# Customers are getting Error 12500 with Google Sign In on Android

Tags: android

I have read numerous SO questions, blog posts and documentation, but am not able to resolve my issue. Details below:

1. Created Google Developer project based on this documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating?authuser=2
2. In my Google Developer project, there is a credential of type `Android` which has the correct package name. This credentials initially had the SHA1 of my debug key. But after I launched the app, I updated the SHA1 to the one of the key used for signing my release APK before launch. (Interesting part is that the Client ID of this credential is not used anywhere in my Android app code, but I guess that is expected)
3. In my Android app, I implemented this code: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?authuser=2
4. My customers get the error `12500` when signing in using their Google accounts. The exception is thrown by line of code: `Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(resultIntent);`
5. I have ensured that my Google Developer project has a contact email, homepage link, privacy policy link specified in the OAuth Consent Screen section
6. I am not using Firebase for Google Sign in. Just putting this out there because a lot of SO questions and blogs pointed to resolving issues with Firebase. I am just getting credentials from GoogleSignIn and then using those to authenticate with my own backend. But since the failure happens in getting the credentials from GoogleSignIn, I am not going into the details of my backend auth code.

Are there any other things I should be investigating to debug this issue? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was aware of the debug and the release signing key, but today I discovered another, hidden key. Apparently, the key used to sign the APK before uploading to Play Store is only used to validate the authenticity of the "upload". Once the upload succeeds, Google signs the APK with another key and that is the APK that gets downloaded on my customer's devices. Adding SHA1 of this key to the developer console fixed the problem for me.

This SHA1 can be found in the Play Store developers console -> Your app -> Setup (in the left menu) -> App Signing

I wonder why this important piece of information is not mentioned on the Google Auth pages.

Comment: hi, can you share any tutorials you've worked with to add social sign in to your android app? the material is very scarce . Thank you.